# Install xp_msver in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures

An application calls xp_msver to determine if the SQL server is an appropriate version. The application will then determine whether or not to install or execute. 
I want to use Azure SQL, but this procedure xp_msver is not found in Azure. Is there a way to create it or export it from an existing SQL instance and import it to Azure? Azure is available as Basic, Standard & Premium, perhaps the Premium has this procedure?

Answer (score 0):

So long as you don't need to run this from Master, you can create your own stored procedure called xp_msver that does whatever you want.  In particular you can clone the results from a SQL Server of your choice.

Something like this:

```
set nocount on

declare @t table ([Index] int, Name nvarchar(200), Internal_Value varchar(200) null, Character_Value nvarchar(200))

insert into @t
exec xp_msver

set statistics time off
select 'create or alter procedure xp_msver 
as
begin

declare @t table ([Index] int primary key, Name nvarchar(200), Internal_Value bigint null, Character_Value nvarchar(200))
'

select concat('insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (',[Index],',''',Name,''',',coalesce(Internal_Value,'null'),',''',Character_Value,''')')
from @t

select '

select * from @t
order by [Index]

end'
```

Which outputs a stored procedure DDL statement like this:

```
create or alter procedure xp_msver 
as
begin

declare @t table ([Index] int primary key, Name nvarchar(200), Internal_Value bigint null, Character_Value nvarchar(200))


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (1,'ProductName',null,'Microsoft SQL Server')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (2,'ProductVersion',917504,'14.0.1000.169')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (3,'Language',1033,'English (United States)')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (4,'Platform',null,'NT x64')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (5,'Comments',null,'SQL')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (6,'CompanyName',null,'Microsoft Corporation')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (7,'FileDescription',null,'SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (8,'FileVersion',null,'2017.0140.1000.169 ((SQLServer).170822-2340)')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (9,'InternalName',null,'SQLSERVR')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (10,'LegalCopyright',null,'Microsoft. All rights reserved.')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (11,'LegalTrademarks',null,'Microsoft SQL Server is a registered trademark of Microsoft Corporation.')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (12,'OriginalFilename',null,'SQLSERVR.EXE')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (13,'PrivateBuild',null,'')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (14,'SpecialBuild',65536169,'')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (15,'WindowsVersion',65536169,'6.3 (16299)')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (16,'ProcessorCount',4,'4')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (17,'ProcessorActiveMask',null,'               f')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (18,'ProcessorType',8664,'')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (19,'PhysicalMemory',16310,'16310 (17102405632)')
insert into @t([Index],Name,Internal_Value,Character_value) values (20,'Product ID',null,'')


---------------------------


select * from @t
order by [Index]

end
```

Comment: Unfortunately the app is trying to execute it from master. If I could assign myself permission to create a procedure in master, maybe...