# SQL Server to Azure SQL: Migration of an application, xp_msver procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-migration

We are currently facing a problem trying to migrate an application from SQL Server to Azure SQL.

**Starting Point**

The application was developed in Delphi between 2010 and today. The underlying database was already migrated to Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (16.0.4003.1) without any problems.

Now we want to lift the database to Azure SQL. So we created a `.bacpac` and restored it to Azure SQL. All tables, views, functions, procedures were successfully created and data was restored.

We want to minimize the SQL Server management, therefore Azure SQL.

**The Problem**

When starting the application, it tries to execute `master.xp_msver` which is not present for Azure SQL by default. It causes an error, see the first of the screenshots linked at the end of this question.

[Link to create statement of procedure on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/1d96HdYJ)

**The Approaches**

We created the procedure, using the hints from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47681591/4351217). And its created! (see second screenshot below)

Somehow the user (admin user) is lacking permissions to execute the function. (see third screenshot below).

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_msver;
```

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure master.dbo.xp_msver, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_msver', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.

When trying to grant the rights it causes an error:

```
USE master;
GRANT EXECUTE TO USERNAME;
```

> Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

**My Question**

Do you have any idea how to bypass the problem? I am not able to find any information on said topic.

[Microsoft does not list the issue in the [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/master-database?view=sql-server-ver16#restrictions)

**Links**

- [Screenshot of the error from application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9TdF.png)
- [Screenshot of the procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I3xQ.png)
- [Screenshot trying to execute the procedure in ssms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6mLi.png)
- [Screenshot trying to grant rights to execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxNNd.png)

**Ideas**:

@siggemannen:
`GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::xp_msver TO USERNAME`

> Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
> `CREATE SYNONYM [master].[dbo].[xp_msver] FOR [USERSCHEMA].[dbo].[xp_msver]`
> [40515] [S0001]: Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.dbo.xp_msver' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

@Agar123:
`GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::xp_msver TO PUBLIC` &
`GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_msver TO PUBLIC` & `GRANT EXECUTE ON master.dbo.xp_msver TO PUBLIC`

> SQL-Fehler [15151] [S0001]: Cannot find the object 'xp_msver', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: You need to specify the procedure in question i think: GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::xp_msver TO username;

Comment: And if you try to give access to "public"?
grant execute on  __ to public

Comment: @siggemannen : Thank you very much for your ideas! It does not seem to work this way.

Comment: Why not :) what error do you get

Comment: > Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

Comment: Weird. Maybe it's azure and master thing

Comment: Maybe you can create a synonym in master to point to another db

Comment: `CREATE SYNONYM [master].[dbo].[xp_msver] FOR [USERSCHEMA].[dbo].[xp_msver]`

> [40515] [S0001]: Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.dbo.xp_msver' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
Does not seem to work, maybe its not possible with azure. :|

Comment: Same if you remove [master].dbo i guess ?

Comment: Probably you need to use some super admin user to grant execute to the regular UserName

Comment: yes, unfortunately. But this is the super admin user that I created with azure.

Comment: Have you tried opening a ticket with Microsoft?

Comment: I imagine that creating your own procs in the Azure `master` database isn't a supported scenario. Why is Delphi relevant? Is this call to `master..xp_msver` just something that all Delphi apps will do when connecting to SQL Server? (i.e. this issue will block lifting and shifting any Delphi app to Azure SQL database?)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I noticed, that the only call, that causes an issue is the call to the named procedure. Besides some other obstacles that we overcame (e.g. encrypted routines) during the migration. So I was hoping to get it working by using the trick from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47681591/4351217).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure hat `xp_msver` is part of Azure SQL Database.

The original [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-msver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=azuresqldb-current) says that `xp_msver` is only part of SQL Server on-prem:

[image]

Eitan Blumin has a query that you can use ([VA2033](https://eitanblumin.com/sql-vulnerability-assessment-tool-rules-reference-list/#Rule_VA2033)) to grant permissions:

```
,('xp_msver', 'GRANT', 'public', 'dbo', 'R')
```

**EDIT:** It's a mystery to me how you were able to migrate a Delphi application from early 2000, first to SQL Server 2022 and then to Azure SQL Database.

Have you checked the compatibility with [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Have you checked the workload compatibility with [Database Experimentation Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dea/database-experimentation-assistant-overview?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! I know that Azure SQL does not provide the xp_msver procedure. In the [other ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47681591/4351217) a user mentions, that it might resolve the problem.

Comment: OK, try and let us know if this resolves the problem

Comment: I tried, it created the function, but it wont let me execute it. :| Yes, we tried the Data Migration Assistant, it simply migrates the data, even views are created as tables and now procedures or functions are migrated. I will try the Database Experimentation Assistant now. I think its no mystery. I think delphi uses something like odbc to connect to the mssql. All version upgrade up until 2022 have been no problem.